# How to calculate delta for adjacent elements in an array easily

Tags: python, numpy

I have an array and I need to calculate delta value between adjacent elements, wondering is there a simpler way to do that like below?

```py
import numpy as np

arr = np.array([1,2,3,4,5])

arr[1:len(arr), 0] = arr[1:(len(arr)), 0] - arr[0:(len(arr) - 1), 0]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `numpy.diff`. See https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.diff.html for more info

```
arr = np.array([3., 9., 6., 5., 2., 5., 7., 5., 6., 4.])

np.diff(arr)
```

> array([ 6., -3., -1., -3.,  3.,  2., -2.,  1., -2.])